# batch to copy in clipbrd filenameandpath of the older file in folderA except the same name in folderB

Tags: batch-file

I have in folderA C0001.mxf, C0002.mxf, C0003.mxf, C0004.mxf, C0005.mxf, C0006.mxf, C0007.mxf, C0008.mxf, C0009.mxf, C0010.mxf, C0011.mxf ecc..

and I have folderB empty for the moment

Consider I have installed on windows/system32 the copy.exe (dos application) http://www.c3scripts.com/tutorials/msdos/clip.zip ( e.g. use in batch: `echo %filepath% | clip 2>nul` )

I would like build a batch that do this: in folderA have to choose the older .mxf file (thay has the earliest date) then have to put in clipbrd its full filenameandpath (e.g. c:\folderA\C0001.mxf) using the clip.exe application, BUT if the file .mxf choosed in folderA is already present in folderB (also if it is present as C0001.avi or C0001.[anything extension] or simply C0001 without extension) then the script have to copy into the clibrd the filenameandpath of the next less old present in folderA that are not in folderB ---> EXAMPLE: if folderB already have C0001 and C0002 and C0003 ---> the script have to put in clipbrd C:\folderA\C0004.mxf

If possibile the batch file have to ask, at the beginnig, to type what is source containing .mxf files (folderA)

If folderB contains all the filename contained in folderA (example folderB have C0001.avi, C0002.avi, C0003.avi, C0004.avi, C0005.avi and folderA have C0001.mxf, C0002.mxf, C0003.mxf, C0004.mxf, C0005.mxf) -----> the script go to the end and do nothing

If the user don't type folderA (source of .mxf files) and press Enter on keyboard, the folderA have to be automatically set to the current folder

ps: I had a script that can recognize the older file in a directory but at the moment I can not modify it to do that: if the files in dir FolderA are present in folder B then copy into the clibrd the filenameandpath of the next less old -present in folderA - than that found in folderB

```
set ext=.mxf
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%A in ("%*") do set folder=%%A %%B
if "%folder%"=="" set folder=%cd%
if not "%folder:~1,1%"==":" set folder=%cd%\%folder%
cd /d "%folder%"
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir *%ext% /b /o:-d /t:w') do set file=%%G
for %%H in ("%file%") do set filename=%%~nH
echo %filename% | clip 2>nul
if %errorlevel%==1 goto:EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `d:\folderB` to suit you.

```
@echo off
:loop
set "d="
set "done="
set /p "d=Type source path (or press enter for current folder): "
if not defined d set "d=%cd%"
if not exist "%d%" echo Enter valid path - try again & goto :loop

cd /d "%d%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.mxf /b /od /a-d') do (
   if defined done goto :EOF
   if not exist "d:\folderB\%%~na.*" (
      echo %%~fa|clip >nul
      set done=1
   )
)
```