# modify batch that copy in clipbrd older filename .mxf in folderA that are not in folderB

Tags: batch-file

Thanks to foxidrive I have this code:

[batch to copy in clipbrd filenameandpath of the older file in folderA except the same name in folderB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23308156/batch-to-copy-in-clipbrd-filenameandpath-of-the-older-file-in-foldera-except-the)

```
@echo off
:loop
set "d="
set "done="
set /p "d=Type source path (or press enter for current folder): "
if not defined d set "d=%cd%"
if not exist "%d%" echo Enter valid path - try again & goto :loop

cd /d "%d%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir *.mxf /b /od /a-d') do (
   if defined done goto :EOF
   if not exist "d:\folderB\%%~na.*" (
      echo %%~fa|clip >nul
      set done=1
   )
)
```

OK, it work very well, thanks!

now I should like to do this:

and then the batch have to nename a file o:\temp.avi with the filename choosed by the batch (and putted into the clipbrd) example: if the batch have choose (into folderA) C0001.mxf, it have to rename o:\temp.avi --------> C0001.avi

Answer (score 0):

Add the line in the middle between the other two.

```
  echo %%~fa|clip >nul
  ren "o:\temp.avi" "%%~nxa.avi"
  set done=1
```

Read the help section on how Stack Overflow works: https://stackoverflow.com/tour